# Export Unity Project as Android Studio Project via Command Line

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a unity3D project and I want to build to android target.
But how to specific the 'Export Project' flag in command line argument?
[image]
Anyone knows?

My build script:

```
BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
buildPlayerOptions.scenes = scenes;
buildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = "AndroidBuild";
buildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.Android;
buildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(buildPlayerOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update `Export Project` option in `Player Settings` you will have to set `BuildOptions` with `AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer`. You can find more information here: [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer.html).

There is also way to update this using `UnityEditor` settings:

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.exportAsGoogleAndroidProject = true;
```